# Get total record count for a query in zend lucene search?

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

HI
I have used **"setResultSetLimit(1000)**" method to limit results to 1000 records. The good thing is It helps to save server resources, but there is noway to get full record count for a query. Is any one know how to get full hit count?

TX

Answer (score 0):

Its not possiblie within my tries...

I suggest u to make a full search store results making a cache file maybe or session and use zend_paginator array adapter

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so easy or I didn't understand the question ?

```
$results = $index->find("saerch term");
echo count($results); // you will get count
```